# Need help with a RewriteRule - Apache

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Here's what I want to do:

```
http://www.mysite.com/      >    http://www.mysite.com/index.php
http://www.mysite.com/asd   >    http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=$1
```

`asd` will be the name of the page(s) that get appended to index.php's $page variable.

My current rewrite rule successfully redirects the requested page but fails to load the default index.php page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([\w]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

How do I fix this? :/

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have one rule that matches just the /:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php [L]
```

And then your other one:

```
RewriteRule ^/([\w]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Isn't `[\w]` redundant? I think `\w` is enough.

Comment: I would say it was redundant. I find that RewriteRules have a tendency to not work in unexpected ways, so I left it in.

Answer (score 1):

For mine, i simply pass the entire path to the index page.

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?page=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Then use `list()` and `explode()` to chunk it up.

```
list( $param1, $param2, $param3 ) = explode( "/", $_GET['page'] );
```

Otherwise, you're going to need two rules.

Or use the same rule and on the / page have an empty ?page= parameter.